# Store credit in partial credit memo

Tags: magento2, creditmemo, store-credit

I used store credit on checkout first my order total is 120. After I use store credit 40 then my order total 80 rest of amount paid through cash on delivery.That i fully understand.

On Admin side I create partially invoice of one one product total three product.

I need to create memo for that 1st invoice total is proper suborder + shipping + tax - Store credit (40).

After on second credit memo of second invoice the total was  there sutotal + store credit(previous credit memo grand total).

The second credit memo Store credit I am not understand why added can anyone please explain.

[image]